# How to share jacoco exec files between multilple Jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jacoco

I have several Java projects that runs on several Jenkins jobs with Gradle and Jacoco plugins.

Let's say I have two jobs:

- core
- app

The core job, pulls from SVN to his workspace: */Jenkins_workspace/core/*, then builds and then creates its jacoco exec file. It works fine and I can see the code coverage.

The app job, pulls from SVN to his workspace: */Jenkins_workspace/app/*, then builds and then creates its jacoco exec file. It works fine and I can see the code coverage

However inside the app job there were some tests that actullay covered part of the core project. So the code coverage of the core job should be updated. I guess the core project should then have access to jacoco exec file of the app job, but they are on two different workspaces.

**Question**: How can the core job can access the jacoco exec file of the app job to update the core code coverage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the jacoco plugin does not allow searching for exec files outside of the current job workspace.

So what I did is, for every app build, its jacoco exec file is copied to the core workspace. The core job will then have no problem findind the jacoco exec file of the app job.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use both "destFile" and "append" configuration.
If you use maven:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-ut</id>
            <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>/path/to/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                <append>true</append>
            </configuration>
        </execution>    
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

or gradle:

```
test {
    jacoco {
        append = true
        destinationFile = file("/path/to/jacoco.exec")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, adding both of those properties worked for me:
`<configuration>  <destFile>${session.executionRootDirectory}/mergedJaCoCoReport.exec</destFile> 
<append>true</append> 
</configuration`